# How to return table's details from another table colum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that takes in a parameter of a Department name and 
returns all the employee's details for the specific department.

If there's no department name passed in, it has to return all the employees.

I'm trying the above code but doesn't display the expected result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectEmployee @name varchar(50)
AS
Select * from Employees WHERE name = @name
GO;
```

**Table structure**

```
[Department]
(
    [departmentID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [costCentreID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CostCentre(costCentreID)
);



[Employees]
(
    [employeeNo] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [lastName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [gender] CHAR NOT NULL,
    [IDNumber] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [salaryLevelID] INT,
    [departmentID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Department(departmentID)
);
```

Comment: show expected and actual results. but you probably mean to join and compare on dept name, of course. and specially handle empty input.

Comment: Your SP makes no reference tot he `Department` table, so `name` is going to have no context here; there's no column `name` in your table `Employees`. Are you familiar with `JOIN`? If not, I suggest reading up on them, as they are far more fundamental than how to create a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Larnu suggested, you need to explicitly `join` your tables together to get results from both where the `join` criteria is met.

In your case, this would look something like this:

```
select e.employeeNo,
       e.lastName,
       e.firstName,
       e.gender,
       e.IDNumber,
       e.salaryLevelID,
       e.departmentID,
       d.name as departmentName
from Department as d
    join Employees as e
        on d.departmentID = e.departmentID
where d.name = @name
```

However, the additional logic of returning all employees when there is no `@name` value provided will require you to make the parameter optional and the script within the stored procedure able to handle both where a value is provided and where it isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you suggest me a good tuto or ebook for stored procedure please?

Comment: A stored procedure is just a SQL script that is saved with a name within the database, that can take parameter values where required.  For most intents and purposes they are no different from running a script you have manually written.  To get better at stored procedures, just read and spend more time with SQL in general.

Comment: I posted below code for additional logic. Can you please assist?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bring back all employees if no name is given you can modify your procedure to accept an optional parameter.

The query you provided had an unnecessary JOIN in the ELSE statement given you wanted to return all employees.  So consider the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectEmployee @name varchar(50) = ''
AS

IF (@name <> '')
    BEGIN   
        select e.employeeNo,
               e.lastName,
               e.firstName,
               e.gender,
               e.IDNumber,
               e.salaryLevelID,
               e.departmentID,
               d.name as departmentName
        from Department as d
            join Employees as e
                on d.departmentID = e.departmentID
        where d.name = @name
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select e.employeeNo,
               e.lastName,
               e.firstName,
               e.gender,
               e.IDNumber,
               e.salaryLevelID,
               e.departmentID,
               'ALL' as departmentName
        from  Employees e

    END
```

So you could run it like this to get all Payroll Employees:

```
EXEC SelectEmployee 'Payroll'
```

OR like this to just get all employees

```
EXEC SelectEmployee
```